# ¿Tener dos funciones de JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, formularios, validación

tengo que hacer un proyecto donde si selecciono tarjeta me aparezca el campo para introducir el numero y si elijo paypal desaparezca ese campo y aparezca para introuducir el email.
Luego tengo que validar los campos

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-18 col-sm-10 col-md-88">

                    <label for="payment">Tipo de tarjeta: *</label>
                    <select id="prueba">
                        <option value="VISA" id="visa">VISA</option>
                        <option value="Mastercard" id="mcard">Mastercard</option>
                        <option value="Paypal" id="paypal">Paypal</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group CVV col-xs-18 col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <label for="ccv">Numero de tarjeta *</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cc-number" name="cc_number" class="form-inline"
                        placeholder="9999-9999-9999-9999" minlength="16" maxlength="16" required>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Este es mi código de script

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#registration').bootstrapValidator({
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    name: {
                        message: 'The username is not valid',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 3,
                                max: 15,
                                message: 'The username must be more than 3 and less than 15 characters long'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
                                message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                            },
                            different: {
                                field: 'password',
                                message: 'The username and password cannot be the same as each other'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    email: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            emailAddress: {
                                message: 'The email address is not a valid'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    password: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The password is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            different: {
                                field: 'username',
                                message: 'The password cannot be the same as username'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 8,
                                max: 15,
                                message: 'The password must have at least 8 characters and maximum 15'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    cc_number: {
                        validators: {
                            creditCard: {
                                message: 'The credit card number is not valid'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    email_paypal: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            emailAddress: {
                                message: 'The email address is not a valid'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });



            $('#prueba').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "VISA") {
                    $('cc-number').show();
                    $('expiration-date').show();
                    $('email-paypal').hide();
                    $('validar').show();

                } else if ($(this).val() == "Mastercard") {

                    {
                        $('cc-number').show();
                        $('expiration-date').show();
                        $('email-paypal').hide();
                        $('validar').show();
                    }
                }

                else {

                        $('cc-number').hide();
                        $('expiration-date').hide();
                        $('email-paypal').show();
                        $('validar').show();

                }




            });

            $('#prueba').trigger("change");

        });



    </script>
```

Para validar he usado un validador de bootstrap pues con javascript me daba errores.

La parte de cambiar no me funciona y no veo errores con el inspeccionar elemento y ya no sé que hacer para que me ejecute ambas, he probado hacer un script solo de eso al inicio y tampoco, estoy muy perdido la verdad.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido  a la comunidad, lo que necesitas si no mal entiendo es que cuando el << select >> cambie, inicies el evento "change", recuerda que si necesitas llamar un elemento por su id, se tiene que poner '#' antes y si lo llamas por su clase un '.'

```js
//

$('#tipoTarjeta').on('change', function(value) {
      console.log('el valor seleccionado es: '+this.value );
      /*Aqui van tus eventos cuando una opción esté seleciconada*/
      
      if(this.value == 'VISA' || this.value == 'Mastercard'){
      $('#nTarjetDiv').show();
       $('#nEmailDiv').hide();
      }else{
       $('#nTarjetDiv').hide();
       $('#nEmailDiv').show();
      }
    
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-18 col-sm-10 col-md-88">

                    <label for="payment">Tipo de tarjeta </label>
                    <select id="tipoTarjeta">
                        <option value="VISA" id="visa">VISA</option>
                        <option value="Mastercard" id="mcard">Mastercard</option>
                        <option value="Paypal" id="paypal">Paypal</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group CVV col-xs-18 col-sm-10 col-md-8" id="nTarjetDiv">
                    <label for="ccv">Numero de tarjeta *</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cc-number" name="cc_number" class="form-inline"
                        placeholder="9999-9999-9999-9999" minlength="16" maxlength="16" required>

                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group CVV col-xs-18 col-sm-10 col-md-8" id="nEmailDiv" style="display:none">
                    <label for="ccv">Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="cc_number" class="form-inline"
                        placeholder="ejm@it.com" minlength="16" maxlength="16" required>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, pero no se ni el comentario me lo ha escrito antes o después de que editara la página. Pero, en la consola se me van a hacer efectivos los cambios? He actualizado el código para que se vea mejor

Comment: @NetbeansNoob ¿A que te refieres con "en la consola se me van a hacer efectivos los cambios"?

Comment: Perdona es que estoy frustrado porque llevo horas con esto, soy estudiante de programación, y no sé si se me entiende. El objetivo del proyecto es un formulario de pago con un desplegable que si selecciono VISA/MASTERCARD me aparezca el nºtarjeta y la fecha de expiracion y si clico en paypal desaparezca eso y aparezca un input para escribir un email

Comment: @NetbeansNoob Ya he actualizado mi respuesta, con el resultado que necesitas, si es correcta, favor de marcarla como correcta, saludos.

Comment: Pese a que aquí funciona, en mi proyecto sigue sin funcionar, puede ser por la función que hay antes que valida campos?

Comment: @NetbeansNoob ingresa todo dentro de, `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza pero es que ayer no pude contestar, he copiado y pegado tu codigo y ni aún así, no se por qué puede ocurrir esto :(